# allure report gives different total test cases count?

Tags: jenkins, allure

I have a Jenkins job that everyday at 12:00 AM, it checks out the regression test cases from our git repository and have them executed, and the allure report will be generated in the end. There are total 250 test cases, and the number is fixed as always.

But in some execution session, the generated allure report says there are total 252, 260, or even 280 test cases being executed.

What could be wrong for this number keep changing.

Thanks,

Chun

Comment: Do you have any retry mechanism when tests fail?

Comment: Yes We do have the retry mechanism, for such failed test cases. Would such be considered the extra test cases ?

Comment: Depends on the execution implementation but that is most likely the case